# Lua base64 image string in discord webhook embed

Tags: post, lua, discord, webhooks, fivem

I currently try to make an https post request over a discord webhook with an base64 image string in lua (I cant use dependencies in my case so it all has to be in the code).
Below you can see my attempt which is obviously not working but I dont know why. So could someone show me how my code should look like that it will work and eventually explain what I do wrong?
I hope someone here can help me because Im already 4 days stuck on it because I dont get it how my code should looks like to work.
Also I already know these posts and many other (but I dont manage to implement the documentations in my code correct):
[FiveM docs](https://docs.fivem.net/docs/scripting-reference/runtimes/lua/functions/PerformHttpRequest/)
[Documentation 1](https://birdie0.github.io/discord-webhooks-guide/structure/file.html)
[Documentation 2](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#uploading-files)
[Documentation 3](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#attachment-object)
[Documentation 4](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook)

```
local embeds = {
    {
        ["color"] = 15844367,
        ["title"] = "This is my title",
        ["description"] = "This is my description",
        ["footer"] = {
            ["text"] = "This my footer"
        },
        ["image"] = {
            ["url"] = "attachment://test.png"
        },
    }
}
local attachments = {
    {
        ["id"] = 0,
        ["file"] = mybase64imagestring:gsub("data:image/jpeg;base64,/", ""),
        ["filename"] = "test.png"
    }
}
PerformHttpRequest("https://discord.com/api/webhooks/MYWEBHOOK", function(err, text, headers) end, 'POST', json.encode({embeds = embeds, attachments = attachments}), {['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data', ['Content-Disposition'] = 'form-data; name="payload_json"'})
```